# I can't import modules from my own project

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to import the ApiRequest class that I created from my project_datafit.utils but it's not working, I created a folder called "venv" inside my python folder and in it I created the virtual environment "Ambiente_datafit" I already downloaded all my libraries and I already configured vs code to use the python interpreter from "ambiente_datafit", before the other imports weren't working either, but after I fixed the interpreter they worked, now only the imports that I get from my own project like utils or My models are not going and keep saying could not be resolved, what do I do?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngQnc.png)

It seems that Python doesn't recognize my files, what should I do?

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: I have already discovered the problem but I don't know how to solve it, my project is in a share folder on the Windows network "\\datafit\share\PROJETOS\DataFit_Pro" and this for some reason is making the code not recognize the import of modules from the own project like this class that I created, I tested it by moving the project to a folder on disk C and the import worked normally, but I need to keep the project in the company's share, do you know how I can solve this?